# Realtek 8160 not detected on LFS

Tags: linux, drivers, ethernet, lfs

I completed LFS and it boots but I'm not able to get the networking to work. When I do a `ifconfig` it list the `lo` that is the loopback network but doesn't detect `eth0` and also says doesn't exist. If i do a `ifconfig -a`  it lists `sit0` as well but I don't know whats that for. I also enabled the network drivers for `realtex` but still not working. Any suggestions guys.

I have a Realtek 8160 Ethernet Controller on a Gigabyte board.

Comment: I've never played with LFS but I'm sure you are more likely to get help if you mention your hardware. What NIC is this? Please [edit] your question and add as many details as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the most likely culprit is a missing driver for your network card. You could check this by running the command `lspci -k` and seeing if your Ethernet adapter lists a kernel driver being used (which I suspect it won't).

Providing that this is the cause, you could either tell us here what network card you have installed in your machine (specifically, the line that shows your network card from the output of `lspci`); or by getting and booting another Linux live OS (such as an install disc for Ubuntu or Fedora - Gentoo has relatively small live environments since it's also a from-source distro, though System Rescue CD, which is Gentoo based, reportedly has better hardware support).

Once booted to another environment, `lspci -k` should show your network card with the kernel driver it loaded for it. If you can't determine which kernel option provides that driver (some of them can be a little obscure), either a search in `menuconfig` (using `/` then typing your search term) or Google should be able to help.

Comment: Ok, you were right no kernel drivers being used. I am recompiling the kernel, bt the weird part is i loaded the old config(in which i had the realtex drivers activated, apparently though) and it did not have the drivers activated.

Comment: @Chronix01 Good to hear! The reason I told you this trick rather than just the driver name or kernel menu option is because this is an extremely useful trick for seeing exactly what bits and pieces may be used for your system. Happy LFSing!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know bout lspci -k and was in the impression that my drivers are activated. Nice man. Yeah the next to worry bout is the xorg. :D